# using pass in if statement in lambda function python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a `df` in pandas, python with mostly float values but contains a few strings and looks as such:

```
index  cashflow    date          changeinvalue
0      5000        2019-12-31    9300  
1      4000        2019-12-31    -4000  
2      -2000       2019-12-31    -9000
```

I am trying to use an apply function and lambda function to turn all values in the dataframe to absolute values. However I think I may be using the lambda function incorrectly as using the following code I get the following error:

```
df.apply(lambda x: abs(x) if isinstance(x, str) == False else pass)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Would anyone be able to help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and convert them to absolute values:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].abs()
print (df)
       cashflow        date  changeinvalue
index                                     
0          5000  2019-12-31           9300
1          4000  2019-12-31           4000
2          2000  2019-12-31           9000
```

Your solution failed, because need test elementwise, not by columns in `apply`.

So if need test each value separately use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html), then test numeric `int` and `float` for absolute values and all another values not change (so return back):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: abs(x) if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x)
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning why the OP's code errored. The `pass` issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df.columns = df.columns.abs()
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

apllying per column should do the job.

i.e.

```
df.columns = df.columns.abs()
```